# Отображать разные виджеты в зависимости от значения QComboBox'а

Tags: c++, qt

Как показывать и скрывать сразу по нескольку виджетов при переключении QComboBox'а, использовать методы .show() и .hide() или есть более разумное решение?

Нужно спросить у пользователя вид заливки: если сплошной цвет, то выбор цвета, если градиет, то вид градиента и два цвета, и т.п..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы использовал `QStackedWidget`, на двух страницах разместил бы виджеты управления обоими вариантами, а на смену текущего элемента в `QComboBox` делал смену текущей страницы `QStackedWidget::setCurrentIndex`

Comment: А на одной странице QStackedWidget'а можно разместить только один виджет?

Comment: Нет, почему. В дизайнере можно все что угодно сделать